# Cordova: load links in webview

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, cordova-plugins

I load an external website (with different HTML files) in an iframe in a cordova webview on iOS.

Now when i click a normal link in the iframe (points to another html page), the Safari browser opens with that page. But i want it to change the location inside the iframe.
The only way it works is to overwrite the click action

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

But that is not nice. Is there any way to prevent cordova to open links in the external safari app (perhaps in config.xml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

> This plugin implements a whitelist policy for navigating the application webview on Cordova 4.0

You may want to add to the config.xml something like:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />
```

.... for each trusted domain, where example.com is the trusted domain

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *window.location.replace*, try using *window.open* with *_self* as the name.

```
window.open($(this).attr('href'), "_self");
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova/inappbrowser/window.open.html

Comment: It works with the script i posted too, but i dont want to add the scrict to each html page in the iframe. I just want to say in general "Dont open links in the external safari app" or add somethind to the link (like <a href="index2.html" target="_self">) that prevents it but it is not working.